# El Capitan changes language input after reboot

Tags: macos, keyboard, login, language, login-screen

every time I restart my Mac (OS X El Capitan 10.11.3), the language input is set to "ABC Extended" instead of English or German. This causes me trouble when I want to type my password. Is there a way to set this back to English or German?

[image: These are the keyboards I have installed.]

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to open System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> Login Items and enable "Show input menu in login screen".

[image]

After enabling the checkbox you can choose between several input sources in the upper right corner.

[image]

Comment: I do have that enabled. I was just wondering if there's a way that it's German right from the get-go.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been going crazy over this for such a long time and over several versions of OSX, as well as the latest El Capitan.
I went in the settings above and saw my box for "show input menu in login window" was unchecked, so i checked it. And voila... now my native language still is the selected one after a reboot.